# Finding closed hours in 24 hours format with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to alert some message if station is closed in given hours.

```
if(pTime<pOpen || pTime>pClose)
    {
        alert('station is closed in given hours')
        return false;
    }
```

This is works if open hour is not exceed to the next day.

For example,

if open hour 08:00 and close hour 23:00  and customer selects 01:00 it will work properly and alert the customer

But if open hour 06:00 and close hour 02:00 (next day) and customer selects 01:00 it will alert again but it's wrong.

Comment: [mcve] would be more helpful than that explanation

Comment: What types are the variables?

Comment: @element11 types are string var time = "08:00";

Comment: "But if open hour 06:00 and close hour 02:00 (next day) and customer selects 01:00 it will alert again but it's wrong." Theres your problem right there, you arent keeping track of date. The if goes, is pTime less than pOpen? Sure it is. Also comparing strings with less than and greater than like this is not commonplace.

Comment: You'll probably have to check if the close time is before the opening time assume it's the next day if it is.